# Data load infile_ python and Qfiledialog

Tags: python, excel, load, qfiledialog

hello i want to import data from an excel file or .txt to the database with the  "load data Infile" but the path to my file contains "\" witch is not accepted by Mysql

to be clear this is my PYTHON code:

```
def parcourir(self):
        fi=QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)
        self.Pathfile.setText(fi)

def chargeFile(self):        
        try:
            fiche=open(self.Pathfile.text(),'r')
        except IOError :
            QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self,"erreur","fichier nontrouvé")
        connection = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "", db = "lexique")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query="LOAD DATA INFILE 'self.Pathfile.text()' INTO TABLE tbl_lexique FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
        cursor.execute( query )
        connection.commit()
        ...................
```

Comment: Is that query really exactly what you are trying to run?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably consider using a parameterized query:

```
query="""
    LOAD DATA INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE tbl_lexique 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '%s' 
    ENCLOSED BY '%s' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '%s'
    """

# you can also try converting your windows
# path to a posix path
path = self.Pathfile.text().replace('\\', '/')
cursor.execute(query, (path, ',', '"', '\n'))
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but i still have error on my sql syntax

Comment: when i execute the same query on phpmyadmin it works, so there is no problem on the syntax i guess

Comment: @AzizaCheikhna: It could be the windows vs posix path. try that update I just made.

Comment: no it's already a posix path, anyway i tried the last update but still have the same problem

Comment: @AzizaCheikhna: Can you please update your question with actual error outputs, and maybe the values of your variables? Also, if the path to your file contains "\" then its either not a posix path or its a path with spaces in the naming

Comment: this is the path : C:/Users/aziza/Desktop/final/test.txt

Comment: error:you had error in your sql syntax near 'C:/Users/aziza/Desktop/final/test.txt'into table lexique.....check the manual taht correspond to ur Mysql version

Comment: @AzizaCheikhna: I don't see any "\" in the path. Doesn't the full error indicate the character position where it thinks the problem is?

Comment: traceback <most recent call last>:
 file "fff.py",line 353, in chargeFile cursor.execute(query,(path.....)):
File "c:\python27\lib\site-package\Mysqldb\connection.py in default Iterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
mysql-exception.programmingError:(1064 , "you have an error in your SQL syntax .... near C:/Users/aziza/desktop/final/test.txt"INTO TABLE.....

Comment: @AzizaCheikhna: Looks to me like a space is missing between the filepath string and the INTO keyword.

Comment: actualy it's me,
 i couldn't copy the message from the command line so i wrote it, i must forgot the space

Answer (score 0):

Well it's working now finally :) I just put this query:

```
query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '%s' " % self.Pathfile.text()
query += " INTO TABLE tbl_lexique FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\\\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'" 
cursor.execute( query )
```